# umask permissions that result in no change

Tags: command-line, umask

I am having a really hard time understanding how umask works.

How is something that is 666 masked with 001 still 666 ?

Comment: Why do you think it is?  What commands did you run and what happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A umask value of `001` says that it is preventing the creation of files with *other* *executable* permissions.  (Actually not preventing the *creation*, as preventing the executable-permissions).

A `666` mode in an `open` statement only permits *user+group+other* for *read* and *write* permissions.  So the umask has no effect on that.

However umask does not affect chmod.